# C# LVM_DELETEITEM from listview

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

So, I'm programming in C#, and I am trying to get a item id from the SysListView32, then send a LVM_DELETEITEM message to remove the item from the list view.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace projone
{

    class Hooker
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowA")]
        private static extern Int32 apiFindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowExA")]
        private static extern Int32 apiFindWindowEx(Int32 hWnd1, Int32 hWnd2, string lpsz1, string lpsz2);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]
        private static extern Int32 apiSendMessage(int hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDesktopWindow")]
        private static extern Int32 apiGetDesktopWindow();

        static Int32 LVM_FIRST = 4096;
        static Int32 LVM_DELETEITEM = LVM_FIRST + 8;
        static Int32 LVM_SORTITEMS = LVM_FIRST + 48;
        static Int32 LVM_DELETECOLUMN = LVM_FIRST + 28;
        static Int32 LVM_FINDITEM = LVM_FIRST + 13;
        static Int32 LVM_GETITEMTEXT = LVM_FIRST + 45;


        public static void withdrawProcess()
        {
            Int32 lhWndParent = apiFindWindow(null, "Windows Task Manager");
            Int32 lhWndProcessList = 0;
            Int32 lhWndDialog = 0;

            for (int i = 1; (i < 7); i++)
            {
                lhWndDialog = apiFindWindowEx(lhWndParent, lhWndDialog, null, null);

                if((lhWndProcessList == 0))
                {
                    lhWndProcessList = apiFindWindowEx(lhWndDialog, 0, "SysListView32", "Processes");
                }
            }

            // Create List

            List<string> processes = new List<string>();

            // Loops

            int processItemCount = 0;
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
            {
                processItemCount += 1;
                processes.Add(theprocess.ProcessName.ToString());
                if (theprocess.ProcessName.Equals("notepad"))
                {
                    apiSendMessage(lhWndProcessList, LVM_SORTITEMS, 0, 0);
                    apiSendMessage(lhWndProcessList, LVM_DELETEITEM, theprocess.Id, 0);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(processItemCount);
            //processes.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            //apiSendMessage(lhWndProcessList, LVM_DELETEITEM, 0, "0"); // third entry is item id in listview
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to correct it so it'll successfully delete the item? No, this isn't for any sort of "virus", I'm trying to see if its possible to without directly hooking and intercepting the NtQuerySystemInformation.

Comment: What is the problem?  Where does it fail?  How does it fail?

Comment: It will not remove the item from the listview.

Comment: Why are you writing malware?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As I indicated this is not malware. It is a test to see if it is indeed possible to do without having to hook the NtQuerySystemInformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wparam argument of the SendMessage call when sending LVM_DELETEITEM must be the index of the item to delete; you are passing the process id instead.

The lparam argument of the SendMessage call when sending LVM_DELETEITEM must be zero; you are passing a pointer to a string.

Comment: So, I've changed the lparam to be a int, now for wparam, how would I go about obtaining the index of the item based off of the name of process?

Comment: You would need to send LVM_ messages to enumerate all the items, and search for the item with the name that interests you, but I am not sure that listview items can be enumerated across processes, since you cannot pass pointers across processes.

Comment: There may be some insanely hacky way to allocate memory inside another process and obtain a pointer to that memory which is meaningful within the context of the other process.  I do not know how to do such a thing, but if you are really interested, (and you don't have anything more useful to do with your life,) then this information should be enough to get you started googling.

Comment: So would there be a way to get the index of all items, create a loop, and just remove every item in the listview?

Comment: Yes, that would probably be easier, because the LVM_GETITEMCOUNT (or something like that) and LVM_DELETEITEM do not involve pointers, so there is no need to allocate memory inside the other process.  Basically use LVM_GETITEMCOUNT to get the number of items, and loop from `0` to `item_count - 1`.

Comment: I tried apiSendMessage with LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, it's returning 0. It's almost as if it's not even finding Task Manager. Note: I am testing on Windows 8.1, compiling in .NET framework 4.0 using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Hmmm, well, I don't know, that looks like a roadblock.

Comment: Well, back to the drawing board. Thanks for the help Mike!

Comment: Sure, I wish I could have helped more.

Comment: `LVM_DELETEALLITEMS` lets you delete all items in one go.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, but for some reason it is like it isn't even finding that task manager exists.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be surprised if Task Manager has protections to prevent you from doing what you are trying to do. I would be surprised if it ***didn't***. [Do not hide programs from Task Manager.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/20/10427187.aspx)

Comment: Yes of course it has ways to prevent it, but there are two ways to actually prevent items from being seen. 1 is to hook NtQuerySystemInformation and have everything go through your custom function and find your entry, remove it before its displayed, or 2 is to have a function on a timer, looking for if task manager is open, and deleting the entry in task manager before the user sees it.

Comment: [Why are you still trying to do something that is user-hostile?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx) Now you're talking about playing with system calls; this is just going to go crazier from here.